# On mid common divisor

Tags: nt.number-theory, factorization

Given $a,b\in\Bbb N$ of $n$ bits each and $c,d\in\Bbb N$ of $m$ bits each with $\frac{n}\beta<m<n$ with $\beta>1$ is there a better way to decide if $\exists e\in[c,d]\cap\Bbb N$ such that $e|a$ and $e|b$ than factoring $\mathsf{gcd}(a,b)$ that is of complexity $O((m + n)^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\geq1$?

It is not obvious factorization reduces to this problem and so is there a possibility for a quicker path?

Comment: This does not seem to be a well thought out question. For example, if $n$ is very large compared to $m$, then probably the most efficient solution is simply to try each $e\in [c,d]$ and check if it divides both $a$ and $b$. Similarly, if $d-c$ is small, probably that's still your best bet. On the other hand, if $m>n$, then there are obviously no such $e$, since every number in the interval $[c,d]$ is larger than $a$ and $b$. Please try to specify more precisely exactly what your constraints are that make the problem interesting.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I have updated query